# PHP unexpected 'register_nav_menus'

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

When I try to put inside my functions.php this code:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
'footer' => __('Footer Menu')
));
```

It gives me back the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'register_nav_menus' (T_STRING)

Here's the header part:

```
<nav class="site-nav">

            <?php

                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary'
                );
            ?>


            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); #creates the menu according to my pages section?>
        </nav>
```

and Footer:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer'
            );
        ?>

        <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: `'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),` try with this.Add `,`.Also please update your code with some code in previous of` register_nav_menus` function.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you'd want to register your menus on `after_setup_theme` hook

```
/********* After Setup Theme ***********/
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_theme_setup');

if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_theme_setup' ) ){
    function my_theme_theme_setup(){

        add_action('init', 'my_theme_register_my_menus');

        if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_register_my_menus' ) ){
            function my_theme_register_my_menus(){
                register_nav_menus(array(
                    'header-menu'  => esc_html__('Header Menu', 'my_theme'),
                    'footer-menu'  => esc_html__('Footer Menu', 'my_theme'),
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like (this can be modified)

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'main_menu', 'menu_class' => '', 'fallback_cb' => false ) )
```

You have undefined error because you just straight up went and registered menus without attaching them to a hook.

Comment: I'm stupid, it was a semicolon problem. But thank you for your reply, your code was great to understand and improve my functions! I'm just learning how  to use wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe forgot to end the previous line in functions.php with a semicolon? 
I bet there is a ; missing ;)

Comment: That was it!!! rsrs Such a stupid mistake of mine. Thank you very much for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

your function.php like this and you forgot `add_action()` semicolon 
  for that error was throwing.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','learningWordPress_resources')**;**


// Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
'footer' => __('footer Menu'),
));
```